# Linux - Install manually a service at startup - GitBlit server on Synology NAS

Tags: linux, service, nas, synology, gitblit

I used GitBlit on windows but I purchased a Synology NAS.
http://gitblit.com (An open source "GitHub like" server)

The NAS works with a custom distribution of linux.

I installed the ubuntu version of GitBlit It works great.

But I can't install the GitBlit service. I would like to start the server at startup.

But I try to launch the **install-service-ubuntu.sh** but there is no **update.rc** file on this Linux distribution.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cp service-ubuntu.sh /etc/init.d/gitblit
sudo update-rc.d gitblit defaults
```

So I would like to install the service manually but don't know the Linux system.

Thanks.

Comment: what custom distribution you are using ?

Comment: I'm using the default distribution of Synology

Comment: DSM 5.2-5592 Update 4